# How to call a Visual Basic API with parameters

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller:

```
Public Class GuestController
Inherits ApiController
Public Function SaveValue(<FromUri> ByVal passedName As String) As Savedata
    'Get guest data from database
    Dim guestResult As New Savedata
    guestResult.Name = passedName.ToLower()
    Return guestResult
End Function
End Class
```

And I have the following model:

```
Public Class Savedata
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Just as a test, I want to be able to call this API passing it a value of JOE and have the API return joe to me.

First I tried

> http://localhost:12976/api/guest?a=JOE

But that gave me this error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:12976/api/guest?a=JOE'.
>   
>   
>   No action was found on the controller 'Guest' that matches the request.

Then I found that I needed to name the url parameter the same as the parameter I have defined in my ApiController function.  So, for my second attempt, I sent in this:

> http://localhost:12976/api/guest?passedName=JOE

But that gave me this error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

So now I'm confused as I don't specify an http method at all.

Ideas?  Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using a browser plugin like PostMan and change the method type from GET to POST.

Comment: @N0Alias I opened up Postman, changed Get to Post, and entered http://localhost:12976/api/guest?passedName=JOE into the input box.  I get back the response that I am looking for.  I was testing by entering the url into a browser url box.  I guess I have to test with Postman.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default if making a request from the browser, unless otherwise stated, the request will be a GET request

But as the name of the action is not following default naming conventions (like having a *Get* prefix), the framework is unable to infer which HTTP verb the action accepts.

Use the `HttpGet` attribute on the action to let the framework know that the action accepts HTTP GET requests

```
Public Class GuestController
Inherits ApiController

    <HttpGet()> _
    Public Function SaveValue(<FromUri> ByVal passedName As String) As Savedata
        'Get guest data from database
        Dim guestResult As New Savedata
        guestResult.Name = passedName.ToLower()
        Return guestResult
    End Function

End Class
```